# web application template and spring mvc integration

Tags: html, jquery, gwt, servlets, spring-mvc

i'll try to be very sinthetic.

#### My Background

- No experience with Spring MVC framework
- Strong experience with server-side devel. (gwt, vaadin)

#### The fact

I downloaded a nice pre-built Web Application Template composed by a certain number of html pages (containing charts and widgets with text), javascript added to it (mostly jquery and his plugins) and css.

The layout and the components of this template is 90% reusable for my starting purpose so i prefer to use those "many" html pages in my project instead of use a modern "single page web application"; in the future i will probably change this paradigm rewriting the view code in order to put everything in a single page.

#### Question 1:

Assume that the only thing that i want to "change" in those html pages are the data (retrieved from a servlet, ofc) displayed by the charts and few things more like text titles and so on, is Spring mvc framework (just to mention a MVC framework) oversized for this purpose?

#### Question 2:

In my particular case what paradigm better fits to build a "well developed" enterprise web application? by now, i just have html pages linked by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at thymeleaf. We are currently trying a new spring mvc development with this template engine.

We are taking more or less your approach just that we are building the pages ourself.

I kinda like the idea because you design a page or let design a page and after you add special attributes for loops, text eval and so on. You are not messing around with the standard html attributes at design time so the pages are still designable by a webdev. (until you start using includes for css etc.